# How to minify AngularJS codes with grunt install but without NPM

Tags: angularjs, web, gruntjs, frontend

Just want to know how to minify or uglify our AngularJS source code with grunt instal with no NPM or do you have any other alternatives with grunt?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Where did 'without npm' requirement come from? How do you install Grunt without npm?

Comment: Grunt is just a task runner written in node (it just lets you setup tasks/functions to be run that can depend on other tasks and then runs those in order)... npm is node package manager for getting packages like grunt, when you "minify/uglify" "with grunt" you are just installing some other uglification code and executing it from grunt.

Comment: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS <-- is "standalone" but still runs on node and would usually be installed with npm... why not use npm?  Updated version following the links there too https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2  You can simply clone a repository then run the script using node but npm does simplify the fetching/installing of packages.

Comment: Hi Sorry I got a wrong question to start with. Can I use grunt without nodejs? I would like to use it on one of our websites angularjs source codes.